# How to use extension in object passed to usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Let's say I have ExampleClass class taken from my BusinessObjects library and I don't want to change it in any way.

In my Presenter WPF application I have an extension:

```
internal string Extension1(this ExampleClass exampleInstance)
{
    return "It works!";
}
```

Then I want to display in UserControl ExampleUserControl and I want to display Extension1 property. How it can be done?

I'd appreciate any answers.

PS. I may use mvvm patern or any other, I don't have any problem and this is just an example. I'm just curious is there any way to use extension methods in xaml presenter.

Comment: What you call `extenstion method` is called [`converter`](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) in wpf.

Comment: @Sinatr is correct, you cannot bind to a method which includes extension methods, so what you will be looking for is a Converter to convert your item to whatever the extension method value is